# Xpath not returning correct result in C#

Tags: c#, xpath

I am trying to run an XPath query from within a C# .NET application but getting null results. The same Query returns results using an extension called XPath Helper within the Chrome Browser. Please advise what I am missing in order to extract the data.

```
string query = "/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/ul[2]/li/@data-index";
XPathResult xpathResult = geckoWebBrowser1.Document.EvaluateXPath(query);

var foundNodes = xpathResult.GetNodes();
foreach (var node in foundNodes)
{
    var x = node.TextContent; // get text text contained by this node (including children)
    GeckoHtmlElement element = node as GeckoHtmlElement; //cast to access.. inner/outerHtml
    string inner = element.InnerHtml;
    string outer = element.OuterHtml;
    //iterate child nodes
    foreach (var child in node.ChildNodes)
    {
        txtResults.AppendText(child.NodeValue + System.Environment.NewLine);

    }
}
```

HTML code below. I am interested in retrieving the following. The first 4 I have no problems with:

```
"/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/h2/p[1]"

"/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/h2/p[2]"

"/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/ul[2]/li/div/p[1]"

"/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/ul[2]/li/div/p[2]"

"/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/ul[2]/li/@data-index"

"/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/ul[2]/li/@data-value"
```

[Elements from Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1dMv.png)

[XPath Helper Query result in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpYfc.png)

Unable to paste code. Detected as spam. Link here: https://pastebin.com/NUPbgRWR

Comment: could you please provide your html as text instead of image?

Comment: Hi, done - https://pastebin.com/NUPbgRWR

Comment: means your code successfully returns first 4 ? only problem for later 2 ?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: try this => `"/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/ul[2]/li[@data-index]"`

Comment: That doesn't work, but I discovered that /html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/ul[2]/li[@data-value="true"] does. I.e. when I specify a condition for data-value, I get a result in C#. This is sufficient for me, so thanks for your help.

Comment: It pointed me in the right direction but was not the solution in this case! Thanks